# How to update multiple rows php

Tags: php

I want to update multiple rows

this my html code :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder=""/>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder=""/>
<input type="text" name="blood" placeholder=""/>
<input type="text" name="id" placeholder=""/>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder=""/>
<input type="submit" name="sub" value=""/>
</form>
```

and this my php code :

```
  if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $blood = $_POST['blood'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if($name or $phone or $blood or $id or $email) {
      $res_11 = mysql_query("UPDATE `general_info` SET `name`='$name',`phone`='$phone',`blood`='$blood',`id_2`='$id',`email`='$email'  WHERE `id`='1'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
  }else{
    echo "ERROR";
  }
```

i have table like this

```
name | phone | blood
```

and i want if some body update just one row update

if write just new phone update just phone in database

Comment: your PHP contains syntax errors. Plus, stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated

Comment: @raptor thank you i use mysqli_* but i just but this code to ask how to update multiple rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
     $subQuery = "";
     if(isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] != "") {
         $subQuery .= " name = '". $_POST['name'] ."',";
                $name = $_POST['name'];
     }
     if(isset($_POST['phone']) && $_POST['phone'] != "") {
         $subQuery .= " phone = '". $_POST['phone'] ."',";
                 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
     }
     if(isset($_POST['blood']) && $_POST['blood'] != "") {
         $subQuery .= " blood = ". $_POST['blood'] .",";
                 $blood = $_POST['blood'];
     }

     if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != "") {
         $subQuery .= " email= '". $_POST['email'] ."',";
                 $email = $_POST['email'];
     }
     if(isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] != "") {
         $subQuery .= " id_2 = '". $_POST['id'] ."',";
                 $id = $_POST['id'];
     }

    if($name or $phone or $blood or $id or $email) {
      $res_11 = mysql_query("UPDATE `general_info` SET ". substr($subQuery, 0, -1) ."  WHERE `id`='1'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
  }else{
    echo "ERROR";
  }
```

Comment: @user4965442  Now check it. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you trying to do. But don't use **mysql** use PDO or mysqli.

```
if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $blood = $_POST['blood'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    //check if not empty
    if ($name != "" && $phone != "" && $blood != "" && $id != "" && $email != "") {
        $res_11 = mysql_query("UPDATE `general_info` SET `name`='$name',`phone`='$phone',`blood`='$blood',`id_2`='$id',`email`='$email'  WHERE `id`='1'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
} else {
    echo "ERROR";
}
```